# Pegar id dos ckeck box marcado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso pega o id dos `check box` marcados. Estou montando os check dinamicamentes da forma a seguir:

```
<li class="item item-checkbox widget uib_w_69" data-uib="ionic/checkbox" data-
ver="0">
     <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="codigoPessoaPresente" value="'+pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO+'" type="hidden">
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
     </label>'+ pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO +'
</li>
```

Como posso fazer isto ?

Comment: Veja este código usando jquery. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVWXaK?editors=101. O Funcionamento é bem simples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function cbx1(){
    var arr = []; /* Cria array com todos os names dos check selecionados */
    var itens = document.querySelectorAll('.check:checked'); /* Busca todos os elementos com o class .checked e que possuam um atributo checked. Nesse caso somente radio e checkbox possuem tal atributo */
    for(var i in itens)
       arr.push(itens[i].name); /* Inclui name do elemento em um array*/

    alert(arr);
    return arr /* Retorna esse array */;
}

function cbx2(){
    var arr = [];/* Cria array com todos os names dos check selecionados */
    $('.check:checked').each(function(item){ /* Busca todos os elementos com o class .checked e que possuam um atributo checked. Nesse caso somente radio e checkbox possuem tal atributo */
        arr.push($(this).attr("name"));/* Inclui name do elemento em um array*/
    });
    alert(arr);
    return arr /* Retorna esse array */;
}

function cbx3(){
    var arr = []/* Cria array com todos os names dos check selecionados */;
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('check') /* Busca todos os elementos com o class check */;
    for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
        if(inputElements[i].checked) /* Verifique se o elemento em questão está com o atributo checked marcado */
        arr.push(inputElements[i].name) /* Inclui name do elemento em um array*/;
    }
    alert(arr)
    return arr/* Retorna esse array */;
}
```

```html
<input class='check' type='checkbox' name='check1' />
<input class='check' type='checkbox' name='check2' />
<input class='check' type='checkbox' name='check3' />
<input class='check' type='checkbox' name='check4' />
<input class='check' type='checkbox' name='check5' />
<button onclick='cbx1()'>Pegar cbx1</button>
<button onclick='cbx2()'>Pegar cbx2</button>
<button onclick='cbx3()'>Pegar cbx3</button>
```

**No HTML:**

```
 <input type="checkbox" checked class="messageCheckbox">
```

**Navegadores mais novos:**

```
function cbx1(){
    var arr = [];
    var itens = document.querySelectorAll('.check:checked');
    for(var i in itens)
        if(itens[i].checked)
            arr.push(itens[i].name);

    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

**Usando jQuery:**

```
function cbx2(){
    var arr = [];
    $('.check:checked').each(function(item){
        arr.push($(this).attr("name"));
    });
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

**Javascript puro sem jQuery:**

```
function cbx3(){
    var arr = [];
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
    for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
        if(inputElements[i].checked)
        arr.push(inputElements[i].name);
    }
    console.log(arr)
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Desta forma ele irá pegar todos os checkados ?

Comment: Gostaria que explica-se o código

Comment: Se você vai poder ter mais de um checkbox marcado irá precisar utilizar vários names. Um para cada marcado. Se for isso fale que mudou meu exemplo. Nesse caso que passei seria para pega um valor de um único checkbox

Comment: sim, Porque cada check é para uma pessoa, isso é um sistema de presença.

Comment: OK, vou editar e já posto

Comment: @RenanRodrigues veja agora

Comment: tem como explicar o codigo ?

Comment: Tem sim, mais agora estou enrolado, mais tarde posto auqi OK?

Comment: ok, fico aguardando

Comment: Embora esta resposta esteja a resolver o problema do user, a falta de explicação da mesma é ... mau.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues da uma olhada no código que editei

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo auxilio.

Comment: Tive alguns contra-tempos no meu trabalho ontem e por isso não consegui postar antes. Abraços!

Answer (score 1):

```
function getIdCheckBoxByLi(_this){
    var id = null;
    if(jQuery(_this).is(':checked')){
        id = jQuery(_this).parents('li:eq(0)').find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('id');
    }
    return id;
}

jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e){
    var id;
    if(id = getIdCheckBoxByLi(this)){
        console.log(id);
    }
});
```